# Cs50 Finance Form Error 500 when filled in wrong

Tags: python, forms, if-statement, cs50

I am trying to provide error message when user write a wrong stock name. However, I am getting an internal server error always.

```
@app.route("/quote", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def quote():
"""Get stock quote."""
if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template("quote.html")
    
else:
    x =lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))
    name =x["name"]
    price =x["price"]
    
    #apology message for none value CIKMIYOOOO
    if x["name"] == None:
        return apology("Stock doesn't exist",403)
```

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error is reported in the traceback which can be found in the flask terminal. It is likely coming here `if x["name"] == None:` with a "None type object is not subscriptable". What does `lookup` return when the stock is not found?

Comment: according to pre-given formule lookup returns None. Eventhough it says None and it return None. When I write None in the code it isn't working.  I am trying to find out why it is not working because all my other error checks are working. @DinoCoderSaurus

Comment: Oh I found the reason. I think I wrote the main function part before the error check part so it was trying to work like fine but because there wasn't value it wasn't working. Thanks for your help.@DinoCoderSaurus